# Prove non-existance of limit: $f(x,y) = \frac{xy\sin(\frac{x}{y})}{x^2 + |y|^3}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I need to prove that $f(x,y) = \frac{xy^2\sin(\frac{x}{y})}{x^2 + |y|^3}$ does not tend to $0$ when $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$.

In order to do so, I would need to find some direction $\alpha$ such that $f(\alpha(t))$ approaches to some value $L \neq 0$ as $(x,y)$ approaches the origin.

The problem is that I can't seem to find that direction. What could I try?

I found  $$f(x^\frac{1}{2}, x^\frac{1}{3}) = \frac{x^\frac{7}{6}  \sin(x^\frac{-1}{6})}{2x} = \frac{x^\frac{1}{6}  \sin(x^\frac{-1}{6})}{2} = \frac{\sin(x^\frac{-1}{6})}{2 x^\frac{-1}{6}} \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Try $\alpha(t)=(t,kt)$ with $k\neq 0$.

Comment: Simply use $(kt,t)$ as mentioned above and assume $K>0$ You can see the the limit depends on path and hence is non-existent.

Comment: The linear limits all give zero.  You have the right idea, just try it with a coefficients. Try $f(ax^{1/2},x^{1/3})$.  The limit will depend on $a$.

Comment: Right, I get it. Though I made a mistake in the function, it as missing a square on $y$. But it should be the same idea, right?

Answer (score 1):

Using the path $(kt,t)$ as $t\to 0$ and assuming $k>0$

$$L=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{kt.t \sin k}{k^2t^2+|t|^3}$$

$$L=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{k\sin k}{k^2+\frac{|t|^3}{t^2}}$$

Whether you approach it from positive or negative side the answer will be

$$L=\frac{\sin k}{k}$$

Which is dependant on the path that is $k$.

Which shows that there's no unique value of $L$ hence your limit doesn't exist.

Note that your limit is correct but only showing that limit across a fixed path exist and $L\neq 0$ doesn't mean it does exist or not. You have to show it's independent of path aswell.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to mention that I had already evaluated the limit of $f(x,x)$. So I knew that if the limit existed, it should be 0 for all paths.

I made a typo in the function definition, it was missing a square on $y$, which I think is what made it complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Used polar coordinates $x=r\cos\phi, y=r\sin\phi$ and compute the limit $r \rightarrow 0$. The result is
\begin{align}
\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{r^2\cos\phi\sin\phi \cdot \sin(\cot\phi)}{r^2 \cos^2\phi + |r\sin\phi|^3} 
&= 
\lim_{r\rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos\phi\sin\phi \cdot \sin(\cot\phi)}{\cos^2\phi + r|\sin^3\phi|} 
\\ &=
\frac{\cos\phi\sin\phi \cdot \sin(\cot\phi)}{\cos^2\phi} 
\\ &= \tan\phi \cdot \sin(\cot\phi)
\end{align}

which is a nonconstant function of $\phi$, thus your limit does not exist.

EDIT: The answer of Mann is easier and more straightforward though.

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't have thought of that. Thanks!